# How to stop printer popup on host PC when printer sharing?

Tags: windows-10, printing, printer, network-shares, network-printer

I have a printer connected to my Windows 10 desktop PC, and it's shared on the network for others to print over the network.

However, when ever someone prints a page on both sides, the following notification shows up on both the host PC, and on the client PC that initiated the print.

[Popup instructing user to turn page over to continue printing on other side](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aIrGt.png)

Is there a way to disable this on the host PC so that I'm not continually interrupted by the popup every time someone else on the network prints?

Comment: I assume this printer does not support being directly connected to a network?

Comment: @Ramhound It doesn't - it's an older printer, so old fashioned sharing via the PC is the only way to get it on the network.

Comment: Are you able to get it to work without the OEM software?  The OEM software generated that notification.  Windows 8+ add significant improvements to adding printers without unnecessary bloated OEM software.

Answer (score 0):

If you network the printer (either with its own Ethernet connection, with an Ethernet Print Server or with a USB Print Server), it should not do this.

Print Sharing is most likely the culprit here.

Comment: I appreciate that this is an issue with Print Sharing; I suspect there's a way to disable this on the host PC. 

It's an older printer without the ability to network directly. I'm  not looking to buy a dedicated print server - sharing it via the desktop PC is the better option. I'm just looking for answers relating to disabling this popup on the host PC without completely changing to a different networking approach.

Comment: You need a network printer to do what you want.  I have seen these print sharing issues at client installations. I have used Print Servers on very old printers as well.

Comment: That seems like a bigger solution to a smaller problem. Yes, I wouldn't get these pop ups using a print server, but surely there's a simpler/cheaper solution out there....